# Combine and aggregate column values and create new column label in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe where I would like to combine and aggregate row values in Python

**Data**

```
 id type        q1 22   q2 22
 aa hey         2       1
 aa hey_plus    3       6
 aa hey_plus_1  2       1
 bb hi          1       0
 bb hi_1        3       4
```

**Desired**

```
id  type    q1 22   q2 22
aa  hey     7       8
bb  hi      4       4
```

**Doing**

```
df.groupby(['q1 22', 'q2 22']).sum()
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just requires a bit of wrangling to get `type` to be what you want, using `str.split`.

```
df.groupby(["id", df["type"].str.split("_").str[0]]).sum()
```

---

```
         q122  q222
id type
aa hey      7     8
bb hi       4     4
```